# How is this real number encoded?

Tags: encoding, numbers, hex

Number in HEX is: 3EB8 EDFE 19FE
I know it means 16.131 in DEC, but I don't know how it's encoded.

I checked if it's BCD, IEE 754 or integer, but none of those worked.

EDIT: It's from Parkin Elmer Clarus 400 chromatograph. This data contains time in minutes.

EDIT2: Here is part of parsed data, I only have one example:

```
  Peak   Component    Time      Area     ISTD Resp  ISTD Component   glycerol
   #       Name      [min]   [uV*sec]     Ratio         Name         Amount
     4  glicerol      3,823    52377,25      0,316  butanotriol         0,0159
     5  butanotriol   5,267   165539,60      1,000                  ----------
        suma mono    16,131  2086652,93      0,489  mono C19            0,4887
```

And here are corespodning parts of raw data:

```
67 6C 69 63 65 72 6F 6C FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 04  glicerol˙˙˙˙....
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 86 95 E6 F4  ............†•ćô
3F 40 7E AD 2D CE E1 7C 3F 90 47 23 62 CD D1 20  ?@~.-Îá|?.G#bÍŃ 
3F 24 AB 9A DF CC 8E 91 3F D4 3F F2 F7 93 40 52 
3F C9 6F 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 CB ED 69 
40 0A 5A BC 13 46 09 AC 41 54 1A F3 A6 C3 FE 05 
C0 A1 AB 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 3B 
00 00 0F 6D 00 00 0F D3 00 4A 28 80 00 7D BD 1A 
00 4A 7E 4C 26 4A 16 A5 40 73 80 A7 00 00 00 00 
40 73 C0 00 4B 83 8C 12 40 74 42 C7 CB 2C BB 1F 
41 04 35 1C EA 62 D1 6A 40 DE 7D C4 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 07 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 67 00 00 00 81 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00



00 00 00 0B 62 75 74 61 6E 6F 74 72 69 6F 6C 00  ....butanotriol.
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  ˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙........
00 00 00 00 8A 95 47 69 3F 5A 10 F0 00 00 00 00  ....Š•Gi?Z.đ....
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?đ......?đ......
00 00 00 00 A0 E8 FC 91 40 12 27 A5 BD 8C D6 B0 
41 50 62 7A 34 5A FA AA 40 9C 49 2B 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 16 7C 00 00 16 E8 00 00 16 ED 
00 4D 8C D8 03 B4 0E 0F 03 9D 5F AA C2 8F 5C 29 
40 7C C8 F5 71 CB 11 FD 40 7D 53 58 56 D6 7F A3 
40 7D 5A 4B EA 10 78 82 41 41 1C 1A 6D 3D 44 F7 
41 1F E5 8C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 6E 
00 00 00 64 00 00 00 6F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 72 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
88 30 F9 69 3F 96 12 04 84 DC 1A D0 40 01 F0 DF 
47 2F E1 08 3F 96 C8 38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
CD CA D9 96 40 1A F5 01 D4 4E 32 45 C1 78 D2 E7 
74 5D 17 46 40 F0 7E 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 16 ED 00 00 16 F6 00 00 16 FA 03 9D 5F AA 
03 F4 EA 71 03 E0 F9 FB 56 D6 7F A3 40 7D 5A 4B 
88 CF 98 C1 40 7D 65 32 7A 5F 43 F9 40 7D 6A EC 
E1 92 F1 30 41 21 24 D6 52 75 CC 80 41 21 20 40 
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 6E 00 00 00 64 
00 00 00 6F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 72 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00


73 75 6D 61 20 6D 6F 6E 6F 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  suma mono.......
00 00 00 01 51 EB 85 1F 40 8E 3E B8 ED FE 19 FE  ....Që….@Ž>¸íţ.ţ
41 3F D6 FC F1 41 FD 57 41 18 42 2A 4A C8 FD 16  A?ÖüńAýWA.B*JČý.
41 3B 96 32 3C 2C 44 95 41 13 F2 D1 FF FF FF FF  A;–2<,D•A.ňŃ˙˙˙˙
00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 02 69 85 75 9B 3F 94 89 17  ........i…u›?”‰.
08 08 4F F0 3F DF 47 16 39 EC E5 8C 3F 73 DB DD  ..Ođ?ßG.9ěĺŚ?sŰÝ
08 08 4F EF 3F DF 47 16 08 08 4F F0 3F DF 47 16  ..Oď?ßG...Ođ?ßG.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

Comment: Where did it come from? That'll help narrow it down. It's pretty tricky to just look at a string of hex and determine its encoding.

Comment: If you know that it "means" something else, how do you know that? Is this coming from some kind of homework?

Comment: It's from Parkin Elmer Clarus 400 chromatograph. This data contains time in minutes.

Comment: If it's possible to find out by just looking at the bits, please include some more examples that you are sure of; that will make it easier.

Comment: I included bigger part of data in post. I don't have more examples of parsed data nor I have access to parser (If I had one, I wouldn't be looking for answer).

Comment: Do you have a theory why the block for glicerol is smaller than the one for butanotriol, although the former has more values?

Comment: I don't know why. Raw data seems to be scrambled. I think those blocks corespond to these values, but I'm not 100% sure.